# I/O error: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist;

Tags: android, spring-boot

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: class path resource [storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190130_135103614.jpg] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190130_135103614.jpg] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist.

I am getting this error while trying to upload an image from the gallery.
the same code works when the image is uploaded from the drawable folder.

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showLoadingProgressDialog();

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(file.getPath());

        formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>(); "jpg");
        formData.add("description", "image");
        formData.add("file", resource);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // The URL for making the POST request
            final String url = getString(R.string.base_uri) + "/***";

            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

            // Sending multipart/form-data
            requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            // Populate the MultiValueMap being serialized and headers in an HttpEntity object to use for the request
            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(
                    formData, requestHeaders);

            // Create a new RestTemplate instance
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);

            // Make the network request, posting the message, expecting a String in response from the server
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                    String.class);

            // Return the response body to display to the user
            return response.getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

server side code is

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = 
     "Content-Type=multipart/form-data")
     public @ResponseBody String 
    handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("description") String description,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            bytes = file.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error processing uploaded file");
        }
        return "file upload received! Name:[" + description + "] Size:["
                + bytes.length + "]";
    } else {
        return "file upload failed!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Akshaya did you find a fix to this?